# How to show/hide cell in UICollectionView using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I’ve displayed cells (0 to 9 and Ok,Cancel button) using UICollectionView.

Below is what I want:

1. The Ok and Cancel button will be hidden at first.
2. When user selects at least one number then Cancel button becomes visible.
3. When user selects total four number then Ok button also becomes visible.

[image: Screenshot for problem]

Below is the code that I’ve done :

```
var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Cancel","0", "OK"]

...

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

        cell.lblNumber!.text = self.items[indexPath.item]

        if (self.items[indexPath.item])=="Cancel" {
            cell.hidden = true; 
        }

        if (self.items[indexPath.item])=="OK" {
            cell.hidden = true;
        } 

        return cell
    }

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item) and value : \(self.items[indexPath.item]) count : \(counter)")
    ...
  }
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Save the references to the Cancel & OK button cells in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method. You can set their 'contentView' to hidden initially. Then in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath depending on the number of items selected, you can use the references of the saved cells to hide/unhide the contentView's of the OK/Cancel button.

Comment: Another approach would be to keep a list of the selections (on `didSelect..`) and force an update (via `reloadData()`) that would enable/disable your Cancel/OK based on the count of the list. By the way, imo enabling/disabling the buttons would be much more intuitive to the user than a show/hide...

Answer (score 1):

hi here is answer with example:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var objectNumCollectionViewCell : NumCollectionViewCell = NumCollectionViewCell()

    @IBOutlet weak var lblnumber: UILabel!
    var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Cancel","0", "OK"]

    var strnum: String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionviewMain: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - CollectionView DataSource Method

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return items.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
            objectNumCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NumCollectionViewCell
            objectNumCollectionViewCell.lblNum.text = items[indexPath.item] as String

        if indexPath.item == 9 {
            if lblnumber.text?.characters.count > 0 {
                objectNumCollectionViewCell.hidden = false
            }
            else{
                objectNumCollectionViewCell.hidden = true
            }
        }
        else
        {
            objectNumCollectionViewCell.hidden = false
        }

        if indexPath.item == 11 {
            if strnum.characters.count > 3 {
              objectNumCollectionViewCell.hidden = false
            }
            else{
                objectNumCollectionViewCell.hidden = true
            }
        }

        objectNumCollectionViewCell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        objectNumCollectionViewCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
        objectNumCollectionViewCell.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        objectNumCollectionViewCell.layer.masksToBounds = true

        return objectNumCollectionViewCell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{
            return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5);
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize{
        return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width/3-10, 100)
    }

    // MARK: - CollectionView Delegate Method

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

        objectNumCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NumCollectionViewCell

        if indexPath.item == 9 {
            strnum.removeAtIndex(strnum.endIndex.predecessor())
        }
        else if indexPath.item == 11{
            let alert:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Number Demo", message: "You have Pressed Ok", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "ok")

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                alert.show()
            })
        }
        else
        {
            if strnum.characters.count < 4 {
                strnum.append(Character(items[indexPath.item] as String))
            }
       }

        lblnumber.text = strnum
        collectionviewMain.reloadData()
    }
}

// Custom cell class
// identifier = "cell"

import UIKit

class NumCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblNum: UILabel! // please declare label in storyboard

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if "OK" & "CANCEL" both buttons are hidden first , you can use the textfield in which the text is printed by pressing any button . 
 if textfield.text == "" {
  okbutton.ishidden == true
  cancel button.ishdden == true
 }else if textfield.text != "" {
  okbutton.ishidden == false
  cancel button.ishdden == false
}
```